# ZF2 Zend\Log + Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-log

I do not know how to configure Zend \ Log with Doctrine2. Only allows you to write directly to the database via a connection adapter or write to a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be it's too late to answer this question but better late than never.

I've found a good post which explains how to create a basic `SQL Logger` for ZF2 and Doctrine.

The approach is pretty simple :

**1. Creating Logger class :** Create the following class in your `Module/Application/Log` folder :

```
    <?php
    namespace Application\Log;

    use Zend\Log\Logger;  
    use Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\DebugStack;

    class SqlLogger extends DebugStack  
    {
        protected $logger;
        
        public function __construct(Logger $logger)
        {
            $this->logger = $logger;
        }

        public function stopQuery()
        {
            parent::stopQuery();
            $q = $this->queries[$this->currentQuery];
            $message = "Executed Query:  " . print_r($q, true);
            $this->logger->info($message);
        }
    }
```

The `stopQuery()` function which is called by Doctrine when it finiches sending the query to the database server, is
overrided so that it could write the current query to the `Logger` object.

**2. Configuring the Logger :** Add the following code in your `config/autoload/global.php` file, to make
the Logger accessible to the `Service Manager` using the name `my_sql_logger` :

```
        'service_manager' => array(
            'factories' => array(
                'my_sql_logger' => function($sm) {
                    $log = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('./data/logs/sql.log');
                    $log->addWriter($writer);

                    $sqllog = new \Application\Log\SqlLogger($log);
                    return $sqllog;
                },
            )
        ),
```

The `Logger` will write data to the `data/logs/sql.log` file. So, make sure that `data/logs` folder exists in your
application root directory.

**3. Configuring Doctrine :** Now you need to tell Doctrine to use the created Logger. Just add the following code
to your Doctrine configuration :

```
    return array(  
        'doctrine' => array(
             /*--------Add this code------------*/
            'sql_logger_collector' => array(
                'orm_default' => array(
                    'sql_logger' => 'my_sql_logger',
                ),
            ),
            /*---------------------------------*/
            'connection' => array(
                'orm_default' => array(
                    'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                    'params' => array(
                        'host' => 'localhost',
                        'port' => '3306',
                        'user' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password',
                        'dbname' => 'dbname',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

With the above configuration of `Zend\Log` and `Doctrine2`, you'll get all the query data logged in the
`data/log/sql.log` file.

Please see this [Sql Logger for ZF2 and Doctrine](http://erichutson.com/creating-a-quick-sql-logger-for-zf2-and-doctrine/) for more details.